# UIAlertView with cocos2d and scene transition

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uialertview

I currently have a scene in my cocos2d application that has a UIAlertView to alert the user that if they start a new game, it will erase the old. Once they acknowledge this, it should transition to the play scene. I am getting the following error when clicking the "Yes" button:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa81afc0'
```

Here's the code:

```
-(id) init
{
    CCMenuItemSprite *newMenuItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:new
                                                             selectedSprite:newSelected
                                                             disabledSprite:nil
                                                                     target:self
                                                                   selector:@selector(onPlayClicked:)];

    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:nil];

    if ([name length] > 0) {
        [menu addChild:contMenuItem];
    }

    [menu addChild:newMenuItem];
    [menu addChild:optionMenuItem];
    [menu alignItemsVertically];
    menu.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height - (winSize.height * 0.70));
    [self addChild:menu z:1];
}

- (void)onPlayClicked:(id)sender
{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button.mp3"];
    NSString *name = [[GameManager sharedGameManager] getName];

    if ([name length] > 0) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" message:@"Starting a new game will delete your old game" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[PlayScene scene]];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [[GameManager sharedGameManager] resetGameState];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[PlayScene scene]];
    }
}
```

Comment: what line does the error occur? Add an exception breakpoint to see it.

Comment: It errors on the [[CCDirector sharedDirectory] replaceScene:[PlayScene scene]]; in the 'clickedButtonAtIndex' callback.

Comment: An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'UIAlertView' object (zombie) at address: 0x13fdbfb0. Why is this happening? I don't have any properties in my MenuScene, what message is being sent to the UIAlertView? I've tried to retain it to no avail. It's like if I do more than one thing in the callback it dies. I can comment out either line and it works.